# Drop down select to change a second drop down select automatically

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a webpage where I have a form with several areas to input text and two drop down select options countries is the first one and depending in witch country is chosen the second should display the estates for that country to choose.
my page connects to my db from where it gets the countries and estates.... I have a table with the country names and one table for each country estates.
so all I'm trying to do is making it change the states to choose from automatically depending witch country got selected with out summiting the form since that enters a new entry to another table in my db.
I seen that using javascript is the way to go but can't get it to work in my case since I don't want to be sent to another page or summit the form.
here is part of my code any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
 $paissql = "SELECT * FROM Paises_table";
 $paisresult = mysql_query($paissql);

 ?>
 <script language="text/javascript">
 function showMe(str)
 {

 <? $estadosql = "SELECT * FROM ".str."_table";
 $estadoresult = mysql_query($estadosql); ?>
 }
 </script>


 <TABLE BORDER="2" CELLPADDING="2" CELLSPACING="2" ALIGN="CENTER"> 
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>"  method=POST>
 <TR><th> id </th> <td><?php echo $row_to_edit['id']?></td>
 </TR>
 <TR><th>Nombre:</th><td><input type="TEXT" name=Nombre value="<?php echo      $row_to_edit['Id_Nombre']?>" 
 SIZE="100"></td></TR>        
 </td></TR>
 <TR><th>Pais:</th><td>
 <select name=Pais onchange="showMe(this.value);" > 
 <?
 while($rowp = mysql_fetch_array($paisresult)) {
 $pais = $rowp['Name'];
 ?>
 <option value=<?php echo $pais; ?>
   <?php if($row_to_edit['Pais']==$pais)
 { echo ' selected="true"';} ?>
 ><?php echo $pais; ?>
 </option>
 <?
 }
 ?>
 </select></td></TR>
 <TR><th>Estado:</th><td>
 <select name=Estado >  
 <?

 while($rowe = mysql_fetch_array($estadoresult)) {
 $estado = $rowe['Estado'];
 ?>
 <option value=<?php echo $estado; ?> <?php if($row_to_edit['Estado']==$estado)
 { echo ' selected="true"';} ?>
 ><?php echo $estado; ?></option>
 <?
 }
 ?>
 <TR><th>Ciudad:</th><td><input type="TEXT"  name=Ciudad  value="<?php echo   $row_to_edit['Ciudad']?>" 
 SIZE="100"></td></TR>
 <TR><th>Website:</th><td><input type="TEXT"  name=website  value="<?php echo  $row_to_edit['website']?>" 
 SIZE="100"></td></TR>
 <TR><td> </td>
 <td>
  <input type="HIDDEN"  name="id"  value="<?php echo $edit_id?>">
  Para agregar preciona aqui:
  <input type="SUBMIT"  name="ACTION"  value="AGREGAR">

 </td>
 </TR>
</form>
</TABLE>    
 <BR>
 <BR>
```

Comment: You cannot mix javascript with PHP like this. You need Ajax

Comment: readability is always a consideration.

Comment: @codingbiz -- AJAX isn't the only solution.  The OP could also include a list of countries and estates and build the second drop-down list dynamically from that.  Without knowing the size of data involved, it is hard to give a good recommendation.

As a fall-back, the OP could set it up so the user selects the country then goes to the next page to select the estate and avoid by JS and AJAX all together.

Comment: well is not that much data, only 20 countries in one table and then 20 tables one for each country where I have added all the estates to each country.

Comment: 20 tables for each country? that doesn't sound right to me

Comment: @zvzej, you need only two tables: `country` and `region`. Each `region` is said to *belong to* a country. In the db world, this is modeled with a *foreign key*, ie a reference from the region to the country

Comment: @Raffaele, see I'm so new to this that I couldn't figure that out ;) how those the foreign key works?

Comment: Let's say that you have `US` in the `country` table, and it has `id = 4235`. You put an entry in the `state` table which looks like `Virginia` and has `country_id = 4235`. Foreign keys are not hard to search with Google, I guess. I even updated my answer with a quick code solution

Answer (score 1):

**I hope you know that developing with plain PHP is a 90s thing. And I hope you know that using `mysql_*` is like leaving your door opened for hackers.**

The thing you need are called AJAX and *events binding*. Basically, you *observe* the first dropdown, and when its state change (ie the user selects a country) you *fire an asynchronous request* to your server, retrieve the list of regions for that specific country and rebuild the second dropdown. If you don't need to support a huge number of country/regions, it may be a good tradeoff to download the entire database at each request: this way your users won't have to wait for the ajax call (there will be a small but perceptible delay), but you'll waste bandwidth. You have the choice.

Regarding the Javascript part, you may want to use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to observe events and managing AJAX, maybe along with [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/). [Here is a tutorial](http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/06/cascading-dropdown-knockoutjs-aspnet.html) for a cascading dropdown, even if the technology on the server side is ASP, not PHP - but you are interested in the JS part.

I put a quick solution involving PHP, jQuery for AJAX and Knockout. You are not required to adopt it entirely, there are thousands of possible variation. At least, you'll have a starting point for understanding *what to study*.

```php
<?php
$countries = array(
    "US" => array("Minnesota", "California", "Washington DC"),
    "China" => array("安徽", "福建", "江苏"),
    "France" => array("Brittany", "Normandy", "Ilé de France"),
    "UK" => array("Galles", "Scotland", "England")
);

if (isset($_REQUEST['json'])) {
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($countries[$_REQUEST['country']]);
    die();
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://github.com/downloads/SteveSanderson/knockout/knockout-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
var countries = <?php echo json_encode(array_keys($countries)); ?>;

$(function(){

var Model = function(countries) {
    var self = this;

    self.countries = ko.observableArray(countries);

    self.regions = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.getRegions = function() {
        $.get("?json", {"country": $("#country").val()}, function(regions){
            self.regions(regions);
        });
    }
}

var Countries = new Model(countries);

ko.applyBindings(Countries);
// Initialize the second dropdown after binding
Countries.getRegions();

});
</script>
    <title>Cascade dropdown</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Country:</td>
        <td>
            <select id="country" name="country" data-bind="options: countries,
                event: {change: getRegions}">
            </select>
        </td>
    <tr>
        <td>Region:</td>
        <td>
            <select name="region" data-bind="options: regions">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the link to the tutorial it does what I want, but since is using another coding that I don't know I don't find a way to use it in my case. thank you

Comment: and yes I know that if i'm using mysql_* anyone can get to my db, but this is just for learning on my own don't matter what I have there is just for me learning.

Comment: So try to learn the best you can :) if you know that mysql extension is buggy and unsafe, throw it away! If you know that not validating user input may cause troubles, use a library! Really, what's the point in learning something *wrong*?

Comment: thanks for your advise, you don't need to know but I'm just learning how to connect to my db with mysql and so I came up to this issue as I'm doing a table on my own from pieces I found here and there, to be able to learn AJAX will be a different story. thank you anyway.