# From a table row with TWO dropdowns, get selected value & which drop-down changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am trying to *update two cascading drop down inside a table* there are many answers on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12442743/drop-down-select-to-change-a-second-drop-down-select-automatically) for drop downs, but I was unable to find help on `cascading updates` inside a `Table` with `dynamically added rows`.

Given the many rows they all have varying Id's `filter #Id` does'nt work. So, **How do I identify *which rows Dropdown triggered the change* & *cascade the update another Dropdown/cell* in the next col of the same row**?

There are 2 `DropDownList` (select box) inside a table row cell. To simplify this, the first is `Country` -> Second is `state`. So a user is expected to select the country and then the state.

---

My pseudo algorithm:

- find which one was fired, and which row (*unsure if its needed, should I wire in place*)
- then fire an ajax call... to get the values based on country
- update the second drop down with value in the same table row.
- Case **1** Change country *and then* change state.
- Case **2** Just change State, *but first get the Country value* in the first dropdown of the same row.

---

I know how to get the change and value in a regular page, but how do I get those changes and update the adjacent dropdown.

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(){
      var data = $(this).val();
      alert(data);
});
```

---

Edit, Stephen request to show HTML

```
<tr>
  <td>
    //DropDown 1 (Imagine Country)
    <span class="projectcodeid"> 
      <select class="form-control" id="Records_1__TCode_Project_ID" name="Records[1].TCode.Project.ID"><option value=""></option>
       <option value="1">Plumbing</option>
       <option value="2">Modeling</option>
      </select></span>                                                    
  </td>

  <td>
    //DropDown 2 (Imagine State)
    <input type="hidden" name="Records.Index" value="1">
    <input class="timecodeid" name="Records[1].TCode.ID" type="hidden" value="5">                                                    
    <span class="timecode timecodeDdlId"> <select class="form-control timecodeDdlId" id="Records_1__TCode_ID" name="Records[1].TCode.ID"><option value=""></option>
</select></span>
    </td>

    <td>
        <input name="Records[1].DataRecords[0].ID" type="hidden" value="">
        <input class="hours" name="Records[1].DataRecords[0].Work" type="text" value="">
    </td>                                                

    <td>
       <input class="bs-checkbox" name="Records[1].DeleteRow" type="checkbox" value="true"><input name="Records[1].DeleteRow" type="hidden" value="false">
    </td>
 </tr>
```

---

Sample image for clarification
[image: An example of cascading table]

Comment: Your need to show the html for a typical row (its just a matter of using class names and relative selectors)

Comment: you have to give different id to all element and fire change event on particular id element

Comment: @bharatsavani I have different Id, I can verify in code. But how do I attach `change` to it, *since they all have different id's at runtime* based on the db row?

Comment: you have to pass id instead of select in jquery like below $(document).on('change', '#id', function(){
      var data = $(this).val();
      alert(data);
});

Comment: @bharatsavani will your `#id` match/filter all the different Id values? and should I add the Id of the `TD`id or the `<span></span>`id?

Comment: Do NOT use `id` elements - you need to use class names and relative selectors

Comment: class is for same this is use in different select element

Comment: you have to give different id to your all select elements

Comment: @transformer, Please show the html for a typical row (and ignore the nonsense about `id` attributes)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added it and cleaned/removed add cols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give both your `<select>` elements class names and use relative selectors to select the associated element in the same row.

Assuming your html is

```
<table id="table"> // give this an id attribute
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><select class="country" ....> ..... </select></td>
            <td><select class="state" ....> ..... </select></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then your script will be

```
$('#table').on('change', '.country', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    var row = $(this).closest('tr'); // get the row
    var stateSelect = row.find('.state'); // get the other select in the same row
    // make you ajax call passing the selectedValue to your controller
    // in the success callback, update the options of stateSelect 
    $.ajax({
        url: ...
        data { id: selectedValue },
        ....
        success: function(data) {
            stateSelect.empty();
            $.each(data, function(item, index) {
                stateSelect.append($('<option></option>').val(iem.ID).text(item.Name));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Refer also [better way to load 2 dropdown in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28627421/better-way-to-load-2-dropdown-in-mvc/28640420#28640420) for details of the code for populating cascading dropdownlists (consider caching the options as per the 2nd code example to avoid repeated ajax calls)

Comment: when you say relative selector, are you referring to `$(this).closest('tr')` I am trying it now... let me work it

Comment: Yes, your selecting elements by class name relative to the current table row.

Comment: Since, I am using `DropDownListFor`, - will stateSelect.append load the `state`s into `<span> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Records[i].State.ID, Model.States, "", new { @class = "form-control state" })</span >` - I think I need to change the 2nd parameter `Model.States`, correct?

Comment: Just exactly as per your comment - `new { @class = "form-control state" }` will add `class="form-control state"` to your `<select>` element (which is what you want)

Comment: And not sure what your mean by 2nd parameter. Initially `Model.States` will be an empty `IEumerable<SelectListItem>` because you do not want to show any options until a `Country` is selected (except in the case where your editing an existing row where the `Country` has already been selected)

Comment: It found the correct row and the correct Country!!!! wow! I had the `.class` on the `span` tag and tried the `td` tag, your select tag worked like magic... but the update of the state is still not working...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137874/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-transformer).

Comment: Hi, using `disabled` prevents the value from `Posting` to Server, *how can we achieve the same - but also get it to POST*

Comment: @transformer, Sorry, not sure what you mean - there are no disabled inputs in the code in your question - or is this another question?. You can always make the input `readonly` instead of `disabled`, or use a hidden input and then display the value of the property as text (style it to look like a input if you want)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you can't identify dropdwns by class or anything.
Assuming that every time you change the value in a dropdown you want to update *the other* dropdown on the same row.
Assuming that you have only two dropdowns per row:

```
$('table').on('change', 'select', function() {
    var $current_dropdown = $(this),
        $other_dropdown = $(this).closest('tr').find('select').not(this);

    /// perform any task you need with current and other dropdown

});
```

Comment: nice one dude :)